# Can I get the php://input stream to read from a buffer?

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is there something I can do with stream redirection?

I also want the output (from echo and printf) to go to a buffer.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asking two questions here. First, [php://input is the same as STDIN](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). Second if you want to save the output of echo or print functions, you should use the [output control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

Comment: I didn't realize they were two questions. I was thinking (hoping) that the same mechanism could be used for both the streams somehow.

Is php://input the same as STDIN for all configurations? I mean, even when PHP runs as a module?

Comment: Yes STDIN = php://input in all configurations. But why are you using it in the first place? Are you doing a CLI Application? Is this a web page? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to test a web page from the command line (phpunit). I could pipe the post data in, but it works better for me if I can get php://input to read from a buffer. That way I can setup the test without spawning a process.